# Как зафиксировать body?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, есть модальное окно код выглядит так.

```
#mask_photos{
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0,.6);
display: none;
position:fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index:10;

           }

.photo_preview{
position:absolute;
z-index:111;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;

           }

.photo_wrp {
    background-color: #000;
    height: auto;
    margin: 35px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 55%;

}
.close{
    cursor:pointer;
     position:absolute;
      right:20%;
      font-size:1.2em;
      font-family:comfortaa-light;
      color: #fff;
      }

.pleft{  position:relative; }
.pright{position:relative;}

.preview_prev, .preview_next{cursor:pointer; opacity:0.5; position:fixed; top:45%; -webkit-transition:opacity .2s ease 0; -moz-transition:opacity .2s ease 0; -o-transition:opacity .2s ease 0; transition:opacity .2s ease 0; }
.preview_prev:hover, .preview_next:hover{opacity:0.8; }
.preview_prev{left:2%; }
.preview_next{right:2%; }
```

Вот как при открытии модального окна, убрать скролл body страницы то есть заднего плана. Подскажите пожалуйста, а то в интернете не чего не нашел.

Comment: overflow: hidden; ?

Comment: @Deonis
function getPhotoPreviewAjx(id) {
    $.post('../photos_ajx.php', {action: 'get_info', id: id},
        function(data){
            $('.photo_preview .pleft').html(data.data1);
            $('.photo_preview .pright').html(data.data2);
            $('.photo_preview').show();
            $('#mask_photos').show();

$('body').width($('body').width());//скрыть скрол бар
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');//скрыть скрол бар
        }, "json"
    );
};
Так вот срабатывает, но через раз только. в .photo_preview поставил 
overflow: auto;

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, **$('body').width($('body').width());** - это вообще зачем? И что значит "через раз"? Оно [или работает][1], или нет. Если в какой-то момент не срабатывает, значит присутствует ошибка или же вы что-то не учли.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/RkzEW/

Comment: @Deonis бывает при открытии окна, задний план не подвижен, а бывает открываешь опять и задний план подвижен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Modal — правильные модальные окна](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148515/)

Comment: @mountpoint Спасибо большое вам.